# Numbered conditions in definition

Tags: numbering

How can I make numbered conditions in definitions, for example and ideal I is called... if the following two conditions holds.

i) A

ii) B

I tried to use enumerate and \item but it just looks bad.

Comment: Are you referring to something that looks like this: [References with `enumitem`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124142/5764)

Comment: ...there is also the following, more general, post: [Using lower-case roman numerals in enumerate lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54055/5764)

Comment: This is unclear: "just looks bad" is vague since it refers to something we can't see. And "numbered conditions in definitions" should probably also be explained.

Answer (score 3):

You could load the `enumitem` package and set up the `enumerate` environment inside the `defn` environment to use lowercase-roman "numbers" followed by a `)`. In any cross-references to these items, the trailing parenthesis should probably be omitted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn} \label{defn:three}
Consider a system that satisfies the following conditions:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*), ref=\roman*]
\item \label{item:mumble} Mumble \dots
\item Grumble \dots
\item \label{item:cough} Cough cough \dots
\end{enumerate}
Such a system is called a \dots
\end{defn}

Conditions \ref{item:mumble} and \ref{item:cough} in Definition \ref{defn:three} amount to \dots
\end{document}
```